# Mask IP after VPN connection is established

Tags: networking, router, vpn

The set up is as follows:

My work from home work laptop (provided to me by the company I work for) must connect to a company VPN to access the company intranet.
I do not have admin privileges on the laptop but I have access to my router which can run VPN etc (Asus GT-AX11000)

How can I mask my IP so that all requests seem like they are coming from a specific location of choice?

Comment: Why? Your employer already knows what address you live at.

Comment: Presumably the employer want to see the employee is working from a pre-agreed location, and not a beach bar in Aruba. ;)

Comment: They wouldn't violate the terms of their employment, would they?! :o

Answer (score 1):

You could run VPN in VPN. Latency will be a factor, but it'll work. Set up a NordVPN/ExpressVPN/whatever on your router, and then run the company VPN as usual. It'll look like your IP is the VPN provider's.

If your company uses a cloud/managed VPN provider, they might block commercial VPN IPs for security reasons.

Comment: I already attempted this but as soon as the second vpn is connected all requests hang